# Keeping track of directory tree in python

Tags: python, directory, operating-system

Assume I have a directory tree such as:

```
rootdir
    |---subdir1
        |---a1.txt
        |---b1.txt
        |---c1.txt
    |---subdir2
        |---a2.txt
        |---b2.txt
        |---c2.txt
```

I want to do some plot operations on the txt files that are located only within their respective subdirectory. Currently I am stuck on finding a method that allows me to walk through the subdirectories with the condition that I should start a new figure when I move to the next subdir...

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
   for fil in files:
       print fil # No means to check that we are within the same subdir
```

The result I am looking for would be something like:

```
rootdir
    |---subdir1
        |---a1.txt
        |---b1.txt
        |---c1.txt
        |---abc1.png
    |---subdir2
        |---a2.txt
        |---b2.txt
        |---c2.txt
        |---abc2.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the directory tree is this simple, try:

```
for d in os.walk(rootdir):
    #start a new figure
    for f in d[2]:
        #pull data from file
        #plot data on current figure
    #save figure to d[0]+/abc.png
```

This method keeps things grouped up by directory. If the directory tree gets more complicated, you can use the three elements of `d` to filter out what you want.